# What's wrong with the autocomplete in the search textbox using apache solr?

Tags: 7, search

I have **apache solr version 4.x** and **Drupal 7.39**. I just want to create solr search in Drupal.

I have installed [Apache Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr), [Apache Solr Autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_autocomplete) (tried both dev version and recommended version), [Facet API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi) modules. I have created the search page, everything is fine except the autocomplete in the search textbox!

Is there anything need to be change? Is there any other workaround for this?

Comment: If apachesolr_autocomplete does not work, either show us how you configured it, or, if you are sure it's not about configuration, fill a bugreport in it's issue queue. We can't answer what's wrong with your config if we don't see it, and we don't do bugfixing here.

Comment: Is that apachesolr_autocomplete module needed any configuration??

Comment: If it does not, and it does not work, then it's a bug and you are asking in the wrong place.

Comment: I have enable the module and based on the readme.txt in that module, I go to apache_solr setting and in advance configuration selected  Custom autocomplete widget in Autocomplete section... I think this would be enough configuration for this module!!

Comment: In that case you've most likely found a bug @Kiwi - please report that to the module's issue queue

Comment: @Kiwi and that's the configuration I asked about. Can you edit this into your question? Sadly, I think Clive is right, and this appears to be a bug.